# Populating an ArrayList with MySQL data

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, arraylist, datareader

I'm trying to populate two ArrayLists (listOfAnswers and listOfAnswerIDs) with fields from a database ('answer' and 'answer_id').

The following code seems to work perfectly fine when question_id=1 in the string cmdText.  However, if I change this to 2 or 3, the ArrayLists remain empty and I don't know why.  Any ideas?

I think it's to do with the string cmdGetAnswersQuery as "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id=2" works...

```
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    ArrayList listOfAnswerIDs = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList listOfAnswers = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions_t WHERE question_id=2";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModuleID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        cmd.Parameters["@ModuleID"].Value = ddlModules.SelectedValue;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            lblQuestion.Text = reader["question"].ToString();
            ViewState["QuestionID"] = reader["question_id"].ToString();
            ViewState["AnswerID"] = reader["correct_answer_id"].ToString();

            reader.Close();

            string cmdGetAnswersQuery = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id=@QuestionID";
            MySqlCommand cmdGetAnswers = new MySqlCommand(cmdGetAnswersQuery, conn);
            cmdGetAnswers.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmdGetAnswers.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = ViewState["AnswerID"];

            reader = cmdGetAnswers.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listOfAnswerIDs.Add(reader["answer_id"].ToString());
                listOfAnswers.Add(reader["answer"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            populateAnswers(listOfAnswers, listOfAnswerIDs);
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Close();
            lblError.Text = "(no questions found)";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to insert record.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

The actual database contents are shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQKX1.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lNLN.png

Comment: Well, I hate to ask it, but... are there even any rows where `question_id=2` or `question_id=3`?

Comment: @Jashaszun Yeah - http://imgur.com/8A913xF, http://imgur.com/3S4lV60

Comment: Year 2k14, and we're still coding using `ArrayList`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer So I've replaced the ArrayList with a List<T> and I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Bhav I've never said switching to generic collections would solve the problem!

Comment: This line of code looks suspicious: `cmdGetAnswers.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = ViewState["AnswerID"];`. Shouldn't that be `ViewState["QuestionID"]`? Unless question IDs and answer IDs are the same thing. Also, your first query sets a `ModuleID` parameter that's never used in the query. Is that an artifact of some previous code, or is it an error?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, thank you! I intend to use the ModuleID parameter in my final query. If you post that as an answer, I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure that this is the problem, but the first thing I'd look at is this line of code:

```
cmdGetAnswers.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = ViewState["AnswerID"];
```

I suspect you want that to be `ViewState["QuestionID"]`.